# Simple Property Binding Not Working in XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding

A simple data binding not working, not able to figure what went wrong although I did some mistakes:

UserControl Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PurchaseStockControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Namee}" DataContext="Me"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I want to bind property namee: but the result was "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Namee' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-840583197)'. BindingExpression:Path=Namee; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-840583197); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')". I could not figure the mistake and spent 2 days on it, although I did some bindings earlier :(.
Control Code:

```
Public Class PurchaseStockControl
    Implements ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Public Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal PropertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName))
    End Sub

    Property Namee As String
        Get
            Return "Some Value"
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Namee")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub
End Class
```

Main Window with User Control:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:z="clr-namespace:WPFApp" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <z:PurchaseStockControl x:Name="Test"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: why do you implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your code behind? if you wanna do MVVM you should go with viewmodels. if you wanna do old WinForm style you can use txtbox1.Text. and if you wanna create UserControls for reuse you should look at Dependency Properties

Comment: @blindmeis: I am not a pro at coding, but learning still, I use MVVM for defining control and then use those controls in form.

Comment: so if you wanna ruse your controls pls look at Dependency Properties, here are a lot of examples out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not set the `DataContext` of your View. In the constructor of your view try doing

`DataContext = this;` after `IntializeComponents()` method call.

Comment: I tried with DataContext=Me xaml as well as in code page, but still the result is the same. Tried the DataContext = this too, but I am in VB.net, so I used me. Still the error exists.

Comment: DataContext="Me" from xaml and do this in code behind

Comment: There was some error with my builder, after a system restart it was working the way you said, thank you.